# "Audio queue get Current time failed" : While adding ear phone audio jack to the iPhone device

Tags: iphone, audio

I am getting the following error while connecting ear phones to the device (iPhone)

"Audio queue get Current time failed" while playing live audio stream.

After connecting the ear phones, I get an alert saying the error.

any idea how to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that your streaming code is based off of [Matt Gallagher's code sample](http://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer). You should make sure you're using the most recent version. In any case, the error you describe is [a known bug](http://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer/issues#issue/3). I worked around it by suppressing the error message before it sets the failure state of the streamer object. It's a one-line change.